# How to show the current site lists names inside the application page?

Tags: application-pages, list

How to show the current site lists names inside the application page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you explain what you are after? Do you want to display an overview of all lists in a site programmatically or do you want your application page to display the Quick Launch menu on the left hand side?

To do it programmatically iterate over all Lists in the current web. To make the quick access menu appear you may want to change the `MasterPageFile` attribute with `DynamicMasterPageFile` (SP2010 only)

For example

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" 
         Inherits="Muhimbi.SharePoint.DocumentConverter.PDF.Convert" %>
```

For future reference, you may want to look at [this resource](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) to improve how you ask questions, it will result in better answers.